# Get all values of Bootstrap multiselect on page load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am easily getting values of multiselect on change event but unable to get values without doing any change. It comes null.

```
     $('#multiselct').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true,
// To get selected values on page load
                onInitialized: function(select, container) {
                      selected = this.$select.val();
                },
// To get selected value on change
                onChange: function () {
                    selected = this.$select.val();
                },
// To get selected values on select all
                onSelectAll: function () {
                    selected = this.$select.val();
                    console.log("select-all-nonreq");
                },
// To get selected values on deselect
                onDeselectAll: function () {
                    selected = this.$select.val();
                    console.log("deselect-all-nonreq");
                }
            });
```

OnInitialized event will get all the selected values in page load.

Comment: is there anything selected when you're trying?

Comment: Yes. I got one solution using  OnInitialized event handle.

Comment: have you tried `.trigger("change")`?

Comment: OnInitialized does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#multiselectbox').multiselect({
        onOptionClick( element, option ){
             // On Option Click
        },
        onSelectAll( element, selected ){
             // On SelectAll Option
        },
        onLoad(element){
             // On Load It will call

             // To Get the Selected Options
             var selected_options = $(element).val();

             console.log( selected_options );
        }
    });
```

> Hope This will work for you.  On Load the Page the "onLoad" is called here.